# UITableView blurred overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiblureffect

In my project I want to achieve a blurred background in a `UITableView`.

So far I already set up the overlay like this:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

self.tableView.insertSubview(blurEffectView, at: 0)
```

Now I got the problem that the blurred overlay is on top of my table cell. See given image. The order should be like this: `UITableView` (which has a bg-color) - `UIVisualEffectView` (blurred overlay) - `UITableViewCell`

How can I put the overlay between the table view and it's cell? Or is there even a better solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your blurred view tableview's background view and it should look correct.

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

self.tableView.backgroundView = blurEffectView
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.